# Was bedeutet "kopfumdrehend"?

Tags: meaning

Ich kann das Wort "kopfumdrehend", das in dieser Bewertung benutzt ist, in keinem Wörterbuch finden:

> »Wenige können so kopfumdrehend über die Phase der Ich-Werdung, die
> Pubertät und die erste Liebe schreiben, wie Wolf Haas.« Katty Salié,
> ZDF aspekte

Comment: Vermutlich eine stomach-turning 1:1-Übernahme des englischen *head-turning*.

Comment: Das weiß nur Katty Salié ..

Comment: In solchen Kultursendungen ist gutes Deutsch keineswegs garantiert. Man kann ja durchaus Wörter erfinden, aber ist diesem Fall ist es daneben gegangen.

Comment: [Komposita](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_(Grammatik)) werden im Deutschen auf Bedarf gebildet, ihre formale Gültigkeit ist also in die Sprache eingebaut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wie @akuzminykh schon schrieb, das weiß wohl nur die Autorin, die sich das Wort ausgedacht hat. Im Deutschen kann man ja Wörter einfach so zusammensetzen.

Sie will vielleicht sagen, dass das Buch etwas im Kopf des Lesers verändert.  Gute Bücher tun das eben. Und zwar wird der Kopf in diesem Fall sogar quasi umgedreht. Das ist ein sehr schiefes Bild meiner Meinung nach, aber das ist Geschmackssache.

Eine andere Möglichkeit wäre, dass gemeint ist, das Buch drehe Köpfe in dem Sinne um, dass es sehr viel Aufmerksamkeit erzeugt. Also drehen sich (bildlich gesprochen) viele Menschen nach ihm um, zum Beispiel weil es skandalös oder tabulos ist. Für ein Buch ist auch dieses Bild etwas schief.

Möglich wäre auch eine Anspielung auf das Idiom "jemandem den Kopf verdrehen" (=  jemanden in sich verliebt machen), oder auch auf "jemandem den Hals umdrehen" (= jemanden umbringen).

Feuilleton-Autoren sind immer sehr bemüht, klischeehafte Formulierungen zu vermeiden und originell zu schreiben. Mir scheint, die beeinträchtigte Verständlichkeit wird manchmal durchaus gern in Kauf genommen und lässt dem Leser Raum für eigene Interpretationen.

Comment: Ich habe das Buch gelesen, und ich würde sagen, es hat keine skandalösen oder tabulosen Dinge. Aber Ihre anderen Ideen können vielleicht besser zum Buch passen. Danke.

Answer (score 3):

Ich kann auch Wörter wie »Senkkopfschraube«, »Bratschensaite« oder »knochenbrechend« in keinem Wörterbuch finden. Das sagt nichts über die Existenz oder Korrektheit eines Wortes aus.

Das Wort *»kopfumdrehend«* finde ich mit Google genau in der zitierten Buchrezension, die auf mindestens 6 verschiedenen Webseiten zu lesen ist.

Ich finde das Wort auch in der Beschreibung einer Hanfpflanze mit besonders hohen Suchtgiftgehalt, die ebenfalls auf mehreren einschlägigen Seiten zu finden ist:

> [Das Ergebnis ist eine selbstbefruchtende, ertragreiche Sorte, wundervoll stark, **kopfumdrehend** beim Rauchgenuss mit gehaltvollem Geschmack.](https://www.grower.ch/forum/threads/lowryder-2-auto-joint-doctor.90879/)

Das Wort eignet sich auch als Attribut für Hochzeitsfrisuren:

> [Überspringen Sie diesen Schritt und Ihre Hochzeit wird eher haarsträubend als **kopfumdrehend** aussehen.](https://zenideen.com/deko-feiern/hochzeit/hochzeitsfrisuren/)

Alles in Allem tendiere ich sehr stark zu der Vermutung, dass mit den Wort das Umdrehen eines Kopfes gemeint sein könnte. Entweder tatsächlich oder im übertragenen Sinn. Beim Rauschgift, weil es möglicherweise so stark zu Kopf steigt und dann den Eindruck entstehen lässt, einem würde der Kopf verdreht. Im Fall der Frisur wird damit wohl gemeint sein, dass alle, die die Frisur sehen, voller Staunen ihren Kopf danach umdrehen.

Bei dem Krimi von Wolf Haas hege ich die Vermutung, dass der übergewichtige 13-jährige Held der Geschichte den einen oder andern Mord begeht, indem er dem Opfer den Kopf umdreht. Genaueres wird man wissen, wenn man das Buch liest.

Comment: Danke schön. Übrigens, das Buch ist kein Krimi, sondern eher ein Coming-of-Age-Roman. Ich bin fasziniert vom diesem Buch (obwohl ich kein Muttersprachler bin), und deshalb wurde mir interessant, was genau über dem Buch in Rezensionen geschrieben ist.